# i am trying to install a netgear wna3100 usb adaptor

Tags: 14.04, ltsp-client

How do you install a Netgear wireless adapter on a Ubuntu 14.04 and where do I download the install package from a windows laptop?

Comment: Please see: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2264020&highlight=WNA3100 " I don't believe this device can be made to work correctly in Ubuntu 14.04 and later. "

Answer (score 0):

Just trigger the code in the terminal

```
sudo apt-get install ndisgtk ndiswrapper-dkms dkms linux-headers-generic build-essential
```

Go here for more info
[Click here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2221251)